# Magento redirecting base url

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have installed a demo site of original site, but it is redirecting like http://demo.example.de/demo.example.de/ instant of http://demo.example.de/
what can be solution,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using PHPMyAdmin navigate to your database and find the  Table core_config_data and see the values of these two fields
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url

They should be

web/unsecure/base_url       http://demo.example.de/ 
web/secure/base_url         https://demo.example.de/